# `type commit` in an annotated tag in git

Tags: git, git-tag

Echoing an annotated tag in git with `git cat-file -p <hash-of-tag>` produces something like this:

```
object <sha1-hash>
type commit
tag 0.0.1
tagger My Name (...)

Description of tag
```

`object` points to a commit object in my case. `type commit` implies this mustn't be the case necessarily. Are there cases where annotated tags don't point to commits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: an annotated tag object can point to another annotated tag object, or even directly to a tree or blob.  These are all fairly rare though.

The `git rev-parse` command—really, Git in general; `rev-parse` is just the user oriented interface to the routines—has the notion of "peeling" a tag, or even a commit, to reach a particular target object type.  For instance, if you want to view the tree attached to a commit or tag or hash ID:

`git rev-parse whatever^{tree}`

turns the *`whatever`* part into whatever it is, then attempts to "drill down" to the point where we get a tree object.  If *`whatever`* is an annotated tag, this follows the tag to its object, repeatedly, until it arrives at a non-tag, which by definition is either a commit, tree, or blob:

- If we've reached a tree, we are done.
- If we've reached a commit, each commit has one top-level tree, so we extract that commit's tree.
- If we've reached a blob, there is no tree to be found, so the command (whether that's `git rev-parse` or, e.g., `git diff` or `git diff-tree`) errors out.

Commands like `git diff-tree` that want a `<tree-ish>` automatically turn whatever argument you give them into the tree, as if you had added the `^{tree}` suffix.  As you might expect, there are also `^{commit}` and `^{blob}` suffixes.  There is also a `^{tag}` suffix, which simply verifies that something is indeed a tag (since no other object type can be resolved *to* a tag), and there is a `^{}` suffix that means "resolve a tag to its object", i.e., peel off all annotated tags, then get whatever object remains.

The full rules are described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Note that not every Git command behaves as described: in particular, `git checkout` tries to treat its argument as a branch name before following the six-step process in gitrevisions.  This means that if the name `foo` can be both a tag *and* a branch, `git checkout foo` finds the *branch* (i.e., checks out `refs/heads/foo`), but `git show foo` shows the result of resolving the *tag*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can tag any git object by passing its hash or other way of referencing it to `git tag`.

In addition to a `commit`, a `tree` (the directory listing referenced in a commit), `blob` (the file contents that are referenced in a tree) or even a `tag` may also occur in a tag.