# What is the mean of ^{} in git ls-remote?

Tags: git, github

What is the meaning of the symbol  `^{}`?
If I check with git log or github the tag reference to the commit in the lines with this symbol, so what is the duplicate object without this symbol.

Example

```
2191702bddc9438e2e8beda602972fdb87a73a15        refs/tags/V1.0
0bfeb6f7a1d2789b3e3d9944edbe680cd7355b6a        refs/tags/V1.0^{}
6bde933efef11bbc75f71df2111b146748220ad8        refs/tags/V2.0
de33c8da37dba18f8d134f6a2a4c1e70da5593ae        refs/tags/V2.0^{}
```

Comment: `<some ref>^{}` is the syntax to *dereference* something (tag, branch) to the commit it ultimately points to. In the case of branch `abc`, `abc^{}` means "the commit which branch abc is currently pointing to"

Comment: What command did you run to get that output? The `^{}` syntax resolves an "annotated tag" to its "underlying object" (see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283734/why-isnt-my-tag-listed-when-i-checkout-with-git-gui#49286861 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858778/type-commit-in-an-annotated-tag-in-git/43859023), but I'm not sure if what you're seeing is actual duplicate tags, or two lines for each tag.

Comment: Looks like `0bfeb6f7` is the commit object which is referenced by the above tag object (`2191702bd`). Same for the second tag and its target commit.

Comment: @IMSoP the command was `git ls-remote --tags`

Comment: @yaronsamuel See [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtemegemv0998em).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are annotated tags.

The other type, a lightweight tag, is a name that refers to a commit. The tag itself doesn't exist as a separate object in the git repository, but it's just an alternative name for a normal commit object.

You would just have 1 line for each such tag in your listing there, something like:

```
1234567890c9438e2e8beda602972fdb87a73a15        refs/tags/lightweight
```

As a git graph you could think of something like this:

```
                       master
                         v
*----*----*----*----*----*
                    ^
                  v9.1
```

However, the presence of two lines, one of them with that `^{}` syntax, means that these tags are annotated tags.

These exist as their own separate objects in the git repository and also refer to a regular commit object.

So with these two lines:

```
2191702bddc9438e2e8beda602972fdb87a73a15        refs/tags/V1.0
0bfeb6f7a1d2789b3e3d9944edbe680cd7355b6a        refs/tags/V1.0^{}
```

This means that the annotated tag object is in the object with id `2191702...`, whereas that tag object refers to commit `0bfeb6f7a...`.

```
                       master
                         v
*----*----*----*----*----*
                    |
                 tag-object
                    ^
                  V1.0
```

---

TL,DR: Lightweight tags would show only the first line, the presence of the second line means these are annotated tags where the tag-name refers to an annotated tag object, and the second reference with `^{}` denotes the commit the tag refers to.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer.   

There is a reason to prefer annotated tags and not lightweight tags?

Comment: A lightweight tag is just an alternative name for a commit. An annotated tag can have a message and will have an author and a timestamp. Annotated tags can also be signed.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) officially documents [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) output format, including the `^{}` lines:

See [commit 51f9d2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51f9d2e56306deeb547c7d62e46598df2d285fe3), [commit a5b0763](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a5b076321a4fe19fd25a3192304cb88abf9aefbf), [commit e959fa4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e959fa452f5928502c26569eadf054a43b815dc0), [commit 21c9bac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21c9bac2c73b0acdb804913a6bc3b83ceb58119c), [commit 00bf685](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00bf685975d7a4a163d8a57d1a666ae6642c6441) (19 May 2023) by [Sean Allred (`vermiculus`)](https://github.com/vermiculus).
See [commit 0f45b5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f45b5bc32c177461793b11650baed4018a740aa) (19 May 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ebd07c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebd07c9f7e5d56fbe9d5816db95ecf137ed447ea), 13 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ls-remote doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51f9d2e56306deeb547c7d62e46598df2d285fe3): document the output format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sean Allred</sup>

> While well-established, the output format of `ls-remote` was not actually documented.
> This patch adds an `OUTPUT` section to the documentation following the format of [`git-show-ref.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d7d8841f67f29e6ecbad85a11805c907d0f00d5d/Documentation/git-show-ref.txt#L96-L102) (which has similar semantics).
>
> Add a basic example immediately after this to solidify the 'normal' output format.

`git ls-remote` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/51f9d2e56306deeb547c7d62e46598df2d285fe3/Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt#L99-L112):

> ### OUTPUT
>
> The output is in the format:
>
> ```
> <oid> TAB <ref> LF
> ```
>
> When showing an annotated tag, unless `--refs` is given, two such
> lines are shown:
>
> - one with the refname for the tag itself as `<ref>`,
> - and another with `<ref>` followed by `^{}`.
>   The `<oid>` on the latter line shows the name of the object the tag points at.

`git ls-remote` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/51f9d2e56306deeb547c7d62e46598df2d285fe3/Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt#L116-L127):

> - List all references (including symbolics and pseudorefs), peeling
>   tags:
>
> ```bash
> $ git ls-remote
> 27d43aaaf50ef0ae014b88bba294f93658016a2e  HEAD
> 950264636c68591989456e3ba0a5442f93152c1a  refs/heads/main
> d9ab777d41f92a8c1684c91cfb02053d7dd1046b  refs/heads/next
> d4ca2e3147b409459955613c152220f4db848ee1  refs/tags/v2.40.0
> 73876f4861cd3d187a4682290ab75c9dccadbc56  refs/tags/v2.40.0^{}
> ```

And:

> ### [`ls-remote doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e959fa452f5928502c26569eadf054a43b815dc0): show peeled tags in examples
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sean Allred</sup>

> Without `--refs`, this command will show peeled tags.
> Make this clearer in the examples to further mitigate the possibility of surprises in consuming scripts.

`git ls-remote` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e959fa452f5928502c26569eadf054a43b815dc0/Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt#L109-L112):

> ```
> 485a869c64a68cc5795dd99689797c5900f4716d  refs/tags/v2.39.2
> cbf04937d5b9fcf0a76c28f69e6294e9e3ecd7e6  refs/tags/v2.39.2^{}
> d4ca2e3147b409459955613c152220f4db848ee1  refs/tags/v2.40.0
> 73876f4861cd3d187a4682290ab75c9dccadbc56  refs/tags/v2.40.0^{}
> ```